# Select Column Based on Maximum Value in Another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume there's a table called `test`, with two columns - `id` and `time`.  **The `id` column is not unique**.

I'd like to get all of the ids where there aren't any rows with that id with a time higher than *X*.

How can it be done?

Comment: Can you improve on the title of this question? It's tagged `mysql` so we know that it's about MySQL, and you're on a Q&A site so it had darned well better be a question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING MAX(time) <= 'X'
```

Comment: MySQL Error 1111: Illegal use of a group function, because you can't use aggregates in the WHERE clause, only the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for what you need:

```
SELECT id 
FROM tableName 
WHERE time > '{X}' AND NOT ID = '{ID}'
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: @Neal: No, it doesn't. Your query shows all ids that have at least one row with time > X and are different from a specific id (the last was not in the question's description)

Comment: @ypercube: Direct Quote:  `where there aren't any rows with that id`

Comment: `where there aren't any rows with that id with a time higher than X.` I read it as `where there aren't any rows (with that id and having time higher than X).`

Comment: @ypercube: hence: `WHERE time > '{X}' AND NOT ID = '{ID}'`

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct id
from table t
where t.id not in (select it.id
                   from table it
                   where it.time>@x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.id 
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT * 
    FROM table tt
    WHERE tt.time > X
      AND tt.id = t.id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT max(time) as max_time, id
    FROM test
    GROUP BY id
) tmp
WHERE max_time < 'X'
```